Passing Props and optimizing performance
i had recently started learning React, and didn't have much difficulty understanding its concepts, except for props.
As far as i know, you can generally only pass props down ( i.e. from parent to child ). From what I understand, its basically sending data from your parent component to your child component right?
Below, I am creating a basic webapp where you enter your name in a form, and then your name input is displayed in a list of names.
To optimize performance, i moved the form component and the name state into a separate file as to prevent re-renders.
From index.jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import { data } from "../../../../data";
import List from "./List";
import Form from "./Form";

const LowerStateChallenge = () => {
 const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);

 const addPerson = (name) => {
    const fakeId = Date.now();
    const newPerson = { id: fakeId, name };
    setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
  };
 return (
 <section>
      <Form addPerson={addPerson} />
      <List people={people} />
    </section>
  );
};
export default LowerStateChallenge;

From Form.jsx
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Form = ({ addPerson }) => {
 const [name, setName] = useState("");

 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (!name) {
     alert("Please Provide Name Value");
     return;
    }
 addPerson(name);
 setName("");
  };
 return (
 <div>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-row">
          <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
            name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            className="form-input"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
 />
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-block" type="submit">
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

I have a couple of questions, first in the Forms.jsx file I pass a name argumet to addPerson.
addPerson(name)

According to the course, it is so that the addPerson function in the index.jsx file knows the name state.  Here, wouldn't the Form component be the child. And if yes, you cant pass props from child to parent right?
Secondly, below in the index.jsx file, when i nest the "" component and pass props to it.
<Form addPerson={addPerson} />

What does the addperson={addPerson} do or mean?
English is not my native language, so I'm sorry if it was hard to read.
Also, would appreciate your help understanding this.
Thank you.
This is my first post on stack, and i am a beginner so i don't have the knowledge to try other things or except other results.
Hoping to learn from this post though!
